# How i can parse the array values inside csv files to array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, csv, parsing

I have csv files with the data format like this :

```
id, name, locations
1, abc, [us, uk]
2, efg, [id, us]
```

How I can parse the locations array data in CSV files to array in PHP?
I have already searched for the solutions, but still do not get it.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) you were asked to when you registered 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: okay sorry i will edit my question

Comment: If an individual element contains commas, it should be quoted in the source file. If it is, then PHP's built-in CSV functions will handle it just fine. (And then you can use explode() or str_getcsv() a second time to split that value further.)

Comment: _Small Note_ The Locations pieces of text is just that a piece of text, it is not an array just because it has square brackets around it.

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading the file using [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) this reads a line at a time from a csv file into an array.

Then use [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove the [ and ] and then [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the data at the comma

```
if (($handle = fopen("My.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        // the location column is $line[2] (zero based array)
        // first remove the [ and ]
        $t = trim($line[2], '[]');
        $countries = explode(',', $t);

        // here you will have to do something with $countries if you want to keep 
        // this array as it will be overwritten the next time round the loop

    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```